# Get delegate handler from event

Tags: c#, events, reflection, delegates, eventhandler

I am trying to get the event handler without doing any changes in MyControl class. I tried to use reflection but I am not able to get the handler.
Following is a code sample.
Thanks

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public void Register()
    {
        SizeChanged += MyControl_SizeChanged;
    }

    void MyControl_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

//[TestFixture]
public class MyControlTest
{
    //  [Test]
    public void RegisterTest()
    {

        var control = new MyControl();
        control.Register();

        var eventInfo = control.GetType().GetEvent("SizeChanged", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Need to get the handler (delegate) and GetInvocationList().Count
        EventHandler handler = ...;

        var count = handler.GetInvocationList().Count();
        Assert.That(count, IsolationLevel.EqualTo(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: The secret cookie name is "EventResize".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events don't actually have handlers; an event is just a pair of specially-named add & remove methods.
For more information, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/07/about-net-events.html).

How the event stores its handlers is an implementation detail; WinForms controls use an `EventHandlerList`.
You can see this in [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,315de363b8a5caba).

Comment: But how it helps me to get to the GetInvocationList() method if I do not have the handler? Or let say, how can I use reflection to get the EventHandler?\

Comment: @ehh: You can use lots of reflection to get the protected HandlerList and the private key object.  However, you probably shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: so how can I achieve this test, I need to ensure that Register method is covered by RegisterTest unit test.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of it's protection level which is currently `private` as can be seen from your posted code

```
void MyControl_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: That's not what he's trying to do.